# How do I make escapes in a .plist file?

Tags: ios, plist

I need to set a Usage Description for my location manager in my apps info.plist. I wanted to force a newline with `\n`, but that just shows as "text text \n\n text text" in my app. Is it possible to force a new line in a plist string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `option + Enter (return)` buttons to have new line while editing plist.

Comment: Oh, it was that easy. Thanks! Up-cepted